# Installing docker containers via chef with staged files

Tags: chef-infra, docker

So I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now, but I feel like it should be a simple fix (it might be my misunderstanding of chef or chef-docker cookbook).

Here's my scenario.  I have a set of containers that host components of my application.  I have a workflow that essentially continuously deploys each of these containers in various environments with different setup for each (e.g. Dev would have all containers living on one VM but for Staging/Prod, containers would get spread out on various VM/hardware).

I'm trying to use chef to deploy these containers via knife and then run a set of recipes on the VMs.  My problem is that I cannot figure out how to deploy staged files for Dockerfile's COPY command.  Here's an example Dockerfile I'm using.  The COPY command is supposed to copy package.json and index.js files to /src directory and execute npm.

```
FROM    ubuntu:14.04
# Install dependencies and nodejs
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
# Bundle app source
COPY . /src
# Install app source
RUN cd /src; ls; npm install
EXPOSE  8080
CMD ["node", "/src/index.js"]
```

My recipe's default.rb looks like this:

```
include_recipe 'docker'
docker_image_build_file = '/tmp/docker_image_build.dockerfile'
cookbook_file "/etc/chef/package.json" do
  source 'package.json'
  action :create_if_missing
end
cookbook_file "/etc/chef/index.js" do
  source 'index.js'
  action :create_if_missing
end
cookbook_file docker_image_build_file do
  source 'Dockerfile'
end
docker_image 'node' do
  tag 'nodeTag'
  source docker_image_build_file
  action :build
end
docker_container 'node' do
  detach true
  port '8080:8888'
end
```

I've attempted to stage files in a bunch of places, including docker/chef/ directory, chef/ directory, and files/default/ directory.  Nothing's getting copied.  The "ls" call in my docker file after COPY command only prints "Dockerfile" and obviously the npm install fails because it cannot find package.json in /src directory:

```
<server> Step 14 : RUN cd /src; ls; npm install
<server>  ---> Running in 5f1dba1fd0cf
<server> Dockerfile
<server> npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
<server> npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/src/package.json'
<server> npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
<server> npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
<server> 
<server> npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
<server> npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
<server> npm ERR! cwd /src
<server> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
<server> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
<server> npm ERR! path /src/package.json
<server> npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
<server> npm ERR! errno 34
<server> npm ERR! 
<server> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
<server> npm ERR!     /src/npm-debug.log
<server> npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I know I'm probably doing something very silly so any help would be appreciated!

P.S. I realize that there are several other options in deploying Dockerfiles but I'm really trying to utilize chef since there are several cookbooks I want to utilize to prep my environment outside of just deploying and starting containers.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this here, in case others came across this issue.  This happened because my source in docker_image should have actually been a directory pointing to /tmp and I copied all files there.  Here's my updated (working) recipe:

```
include_recipe 'docker'
docker_node_data = '/tmp/docker'
directory docker_node_data do
  action :create
end 
cookbook_file "#{docker_node_data}/package.json" do
  source 'package.json'
  action :create_if_missing
end
cookbook_file "#{docker_node_data}/Dockerfile" do
  source 'Dockerfile'
end
docker_image 'example/node' do
  tag 'latest'
  source docker_node_data
  action :build
end
docker_container 'example/node' do
  detach true
  port '8080:8080'
  action :run
end
```